# TypeError: updateElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to update an element from an array by adding an object as a property like shown in this picture
[image]
When a user clicks on a single node button, a modal appears the user fills the form and then it is addes as a property for this node.
But for some reason I get this type error that says that the updateElement is not a function.
[image]

**BTW**, I am using Redux & [react-flow-renderer](https://reactflow.dev/) libraries.
**Reducer**

```js
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  elements: []
};

const flow = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_ELEMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        elements: state.elements.map((e) => {
          if (e.id === action.payload.id) {
            e = {
              ...e,
              options: action.payload.options,
            };
          }
          return e;
        }),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default flow;
```

**Action**

```js
import { UPDATE_ELEMENT } from './types';

export const updateElement = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_ELEMENT,
    payload: data,
  });
};
```

**Node modal**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { updateElement } from '../../../../redux/actions/flow';

const VPCNodeModal = (props, { updateElement }) => {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    instance: '',
  });

  // options
  const { instance } = formData;

  const onFormChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmitForm = () => {
    const update = {
      id: selectedElement.id,
      options: formData,
    };

    updateElement(update);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Modal {...props}>
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              onSubmitForm();
            }}
          >
            <label>
              <span> Instance name:</span>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='instance'
                value={instance}
                onChange={onFormChange}
              />
            </label>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
          </form>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

VPCNodeModal.propTypes = {
  updateElement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, { updateElement })(VPCNodeModal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is while receiving the props.
change

```
const VPCNodeModal = (props, { updateElement }) => {
```

to

```
const VPCNodeModal = (props) => {
const { updateElement } = props;
```

Comment: The error is gone but the elements array becomes empty after updating an element for a strange reason, do you know how to fix that issue please?

Answer (score 0):

`updateElement` is a props was passes in `VPCNodeModal`. So you should update like this with `spread operator`

```
const VPCNodeModal = ({ updateElement, ...props }) => {
```

Comment: The error is gone but the elements array becomes empty after updating an element for a strange reason, do you know how to fix that issue please?